# first and last business day date formula in crystal for monthly report

Tags: date, crystal-reports

Could some one please help me to mention First working day date and Last working Day Date of last month in Crystal Repoerts (8.5),

I need to use last month's `first` and `last` business day date for monthly report generation on first working day of the month.

In record selection I would like to give condition on value date, so that records will be only from earlier month.

For example if today is `1st jul 2014 (01-07-2014)` then i shall get formula in record selection on Value date (say field is Value_Date) as,

```
first day of earlier month: 02-06-2014
last day of earlier month:  30-06-2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Value_Date` is a `Date Field` try belwo formula in `Record Selection`.

```
Value_Date>=DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate)-1,1) and
Value_Date<DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Looks fine. i have one query over here, for example if it is 1st jan 2015 (01-01-2015), then will formula still give me first day of previous month as 01-12-2014 or it will show 01-12-2015 (because year number is still taking from current date).

Comment: Its a tested solution.. you won't get any issue.. it works as expected

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will use these formulas in my reports.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) =1  
   then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+1) 
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 7
   then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+2) 
else 
   DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1)
```